# iOS 7/8 - Detecting iOS Messaging App Opening, and if it has been sending SMS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've been looking around for resources that could possible explain both how to look up the running apps on an iPhone, in particular, the Messaging app, and to also detect when it comes to the foreground and has been sending text messages.

I've found one resource on url schemes below, that might be of some help, but isn't entirely hitting the bill.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

And this SO post, that also isn't entirely hitting the bill.

[Detect incoming SMS and send SMS in ios 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972272/detect-incoming-sms-and-send-sms-in-ios-6)

Overall, I would like to attempt to do this, without jailbreaking a phone, as I'd like to implement it within an app I'd like to work on.  This app would basically just be a background process by itself, which would be looking for a user is sending text messages (does not need to read the text at all though, I'd just like to get a notification).

Comment: There is no public api that will allow you to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. Apple have not released an API for this and you should consider Messages a closed application for the foreseeable future.

Your only option here would be to attempt to find a solution for jailbroken devices.